# creating a page with more views and blocks in drupal

Tags: drupal

How to create a page containing more than one view and blocks without using page manager. If it is a home page, we can easily create by saying promote to front page.
If it is an inner page, how to map that page with more views and blocks.
Without using page manager,is it possible? 
If it so,kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You create a file with the node-page-id, for example node--1.tpl.php, where you make changes only for this specific page, and then you add your views and blocks using code,

```
print render($block['content']);
```

or

```
print views_embed_view('');
```